# Is it possible to Upgrade Atlassian JIRA with an expired license?

Tags: jira, licensing

We have a production JIRA server running on an old CentOS 5 box that needs to be upgraded or better yet trashed and renewed. Anyway, we also have a JIRA license that our local Atlassian support experts keep telling us to get renewed or it will prevent us from upgrading to JIRA v7.

Now, the version of JIRA we want to upgrade to is 7.1.4, which came out before our license expired last August. And the Atlassian License FAQ seems to say it's a perpetual license, not one that will expire and prevent us from using the app.

I read somewhere in the atlassian documentation that the JIRA v7 upgrades **requires** a valid support license - that it won't upgrade at *all* if the current product license is expired. But everywhere else the license documentation seems to say that if the version I'm are upgrading to was released while my license is valid then I should be able to upgrade to it.

Before I dive into the server (well...the test instance of that server) and start changing things I thought I'd ask around a bit to see.

Answer (score 1):

From experience: you need a valid license if you want to upgrade your JIRA instance.

The [JIRA upgrade guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/upgrading-jira-applications-manually-802592252.html) also mentions this as one of the first things to check before you start your upgrade:

> Check your license - Verify that your [license support period](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/licensing-your-jira-applications-802593008.html) is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to run a version that was released before your maintenance expired. Whether some automatic updater will install it for you is another question. You can always install 7.1.4 without a license, and then add your license to it.